# Properly implementing a function inside foldl's lambda function

Tags: haskell, lambda, fold

I'm new to haskell, trying to learn by solving some puzzles online.

I have this function

```
crossCopyPaste t (as, bs) = (take t as ++ drop t bs, take t bs ++ drop t as)
```

which just takes a number `t` and a pair of lists `(as, bs)`

I have another function

```
crossover ns xs ys
```

which takes a list of ints `ns` and two lists `xs ys`

what I want `crossover` to do is take first element of list `ns` say `t'`

run `crossCopyPaste t' (xs, ys)`, take the result say `result1`

get the next number in the list `ns` say `t''`

and run `crossCopyPaste t'' (fst result1, snd result1)` (its result will be `result2`)

next few would look like this

```
crossCopyPaste t''' (fst result2, snd result2)

crossCopyPaste t'''' (fst result3, snd result3)
```

and continuously do this until there aren't any elements left to cover in the list `ns`

So I thought of using foldl since it takes a function, starting element and a list and applys all like this

```
foldl (+) 0 (1:2:3:[])
      =  foldl (+) (0 + 1)             (2:3:[])
      =  foldl (+) ((0 + 1) + 2)       (3:[])
      =  foldl (+) (((0 + 1) + 2) + 3) []
      =            (((0 + 1) + 2) + 3)
```

but I don't know how I'd go about implementing it in the context I described above.

---

this is the `crossover` I thought would work

```
crossover ns xs ys = foldl (\acc t -> crossCopyPaste t (xs, ys)) 0 ns
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start by taking a look at the signature of your function `crossCopyPaste`. A quick check in ghci shows this

```
> :t crossCopyPaste
crossCopyPaste :: Int -> ([a], [a]) -> ([a], [a])
```

And the signature of `foldl`

```
> :t foldl
foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

So from that we can see that the function passed to `foldl` must output the same type that it is passed. Since `crossCopyPaste` outputs a value of type `([a], [a])` the folding function needs to accept a value of that type as an input (the accumulator). So your lambda needs to look something like this:

```
(\(accx, accy) t -> crossCopyPaste t (accx, accy))
```

Note that since we don't actually need to split the values of the tuple there's no need to pattern match on them and we can re-write the lambda as

```
(\acc t -> crossCopyPaste t acc)
```

Now, the initial value for the accumulator just needs to be the initial value of `xs` and `ys`. So we can put it all together like this

```
crossover ns xs ys = foldl (\acc t -> crossCopyPaste t acc) (xs, ys) ns
```

Comment: Thanks for the step-by-step explanation! It works perfectly!

Comment: Note also that `(\acc t -> crossCopyPaste t acc)` is more simply written as `(flip crossCopyPaste)`; or you could redefine `crossCopyPaste` to take its arguments in the other order so that the flip is unnecessary.